# How to get the name of textview included in linear layout in OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I am adding textviews dynamically to a linear layout and want to get the name of the textview clicked in OnClickListener of linear layout.This is the code:

```
m_lvSideIndex = (LinearLayout)ShowTheContacts1.this.findViewById(R.id.sideIndex);
TextView l_tempText = null;

for(int l_a = 0;l_a < m_arrayOfAlphabets.length;l_a++)
{
    l_tempText = new TextView(ShowTheContacts1.this);
    l_tempText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    l_tempText.setTextSize(15);
    l_tempText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
    l_tempText.setLayoutParams(params);;
    l_tempText.setText(m_arrayOfAlphabets[l_a]);
    m_lvSideIndex.addView(l_tempText);
    m_lvSideIndex.setTag(l_a);
}

m_lvSideIndex.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{               
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        String l_itemSelected = (String)v.toString();  //Want to get the name of textview selected here
});
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: a view does not have a name. A view have an ID. What do you mean by name? Do you mean the text?

Comment: Solved the problem using setTag() but this question arises: Can i attach 2 values using setTag because i need the position of textview in linear layout as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with it the help of getTag()

first setTag() the value i.e TextName

```
m_lvSideIndex.setTag(m_arrayOfAlphabets[l_a]);
m_lvSideIndex.setTag(l_a, R.id.sideIndex);
```

and get the value via getTag()

```
m_lvSideIndex.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{               
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        String l_itemSelected = (String)v.getTag(); 
        Integer l_position = (Integer)v.getTag(R.id.sideIndex);   
});
```

Comment: Can i attach 2 values using setTag because i need the position of textview in linear layout as well?

Comment: Solved but this question arises:  
Can i attach 2 values using setTag because i need the position of textview in linear layout as well?

Comment: yes why not, you need to set this two `setTag(value)` and `setTag(value, R.id.some_valid_id)` and vice-versa for getTag(). see updated @user1726619

Comment: Can you please give me some example in this regard about how to set and retrieve both the values?

Comment: @user1726619 : have you tried as `l_tempText.setTag("firsttextview");` ?

Comment: Yes sir,i have tried and solved the problem.Now i have to tag 2 values using setTag() and retrieve them using getTag().I am getting clue about how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add your click listener to each text view, you will then receive the view as parameter in onClick.

Comment: @user1726619 : first make textView checkable then add OnClickListener

Answer (score 1):

OnClickListener works on TextView. Make sure you set Clickable property of TextView to true.

Answer (score 1):

((TextView)v.findviewbyTag(R.id.label)).getText();

I hope this work