# How to create a custom View's layout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-custom-view

In an Activity, you can create a LinearLayout programmatically in the following way:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("HELLO");
    ll.addView(tv1);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setText("WORLD");
    ll.addView(tv2);

    setContentView(ll);
}
```

How do you do the same inside a custom View subclass? There are no `setContentView` or `onCreate` methods...

Comment: may be [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054197/how-to-get-the-name-of-textview-included-in-linear-layout-in-onclicklistener)

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081339/how-can-i-declare-textview-as-global-variable-to-use-in-other-class/14081472#14081472

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Okay, I discovered one way of doing it. Basically, instead of subclassing the View class directly, you need to subclass the top-most class that you would normally define in XML. For example, if your custom View needs a LinearLayout as its top-most class, then your custom View should simply subclass LinearLayout.

For example:

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout
{
    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(context);
        tv1.setText("HELLO");
        addView(tv1);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(context);
        tv2.setText("WORLD");
        addView(tv2);
    }
}
```

Is subclassing LinearLayout a "hack"? Not as far as I can see. Some official View subclasses do the same, like [NumberPicker](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java) and [SearchView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java) (even though they inflate their layouts from XML).

Upon reflection, it's actually a pretty obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you need to use inflate, like this:

```
public final class ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public TextView artist;
        public TextView duration;
        public ImageView thumb_image;
    //A class for the ViewHolder

    }

// Put this where you want to inflate this layout, could be a customlistview
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    holder.artist = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    holder.duration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    holder.thumb_image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
```